# Java generic to avoid ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Here is a piece of code I'm working on. I have a Callback object that can return a specified super type. `Vehicle` is one of these classes here. These classes are used as supertype for other classes like `Car` and `Train` here.

```
interface CompletionCallBack<Result> {
    void onCompletion(Result result);
}

class Vehicle {
    Map<String, Object> attributes;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public String getMake(){
        return attributes.get("make").toString();
    }
}

class Train extends Vehicle {
    public String getMake(){
        return attributes.get("size").toString();
    }
}

public class Main {
    static void execute(CompletionCallBack<Vehicle> callBack) {
        callBack.onCompletion(new Vehicle());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        execute(new CompletionCallBack<Vehicle>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Vehicle result) {
                Car car = (Car) result; //Exception
            }
        });
        execute(new CompletionCallBack<Vehicle>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Vehicle result) {
                Train train = (Train) result; //Exception

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here I get ClassCastException as Vehicule cannot be directly casted to Car or Train. I would like to either call the `execute` giving it a type like `Car` or `Train` like so :

```
public class Main {

    static void executeGeneric(CompletionCallBack<? extends Vehicle> callBack) {
        callBack.onCompletion(new Vehicle()); //compilation error
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeGeneric(new CompletionCallBack<Car>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Car car) {
                //I receive a car here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this because in my case, `Vehicle` contains a map of attribute and a `Car` a vehicle that has some key-value pair in that list. Train has others. My `Car` and `Train` object provides easy getter that knows the specific keys to retrieve data from the `Map`.

The only way I was able to do it was to remove the parent-child relation and build a decorator around a `Vehicle` for my `Train` and `Car` classes.

Comment: Use the `instanceof` keyword to determine if the runtime object is of a given subtype. Additionally, you cannot cast a superclass into a subclass type unless the object itself was initialized as the subclass type.

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm asking for a way around this :(. In my case the `execute` function will always work with the superclass. Maybe my question would be : How to go from a superclass to a subclass without manually copying fields?

Comment: implement cloneable?

Comment: You are asking for something that **violates** subtyping. You want to call `new Vehicle` and get a `Car`. The runtime is right to throw an invalid cast - a vehicle is not car; it's the other way around.

Comment: The rules of polymorphism and OOP state allow for a subtype to be stored in a superclass "container" (since a subtype is technically an instance of a supertype, just more specific) but not vice versa. Imagine for example, a list of `final` fields present in a given subclass populated in the constructor. If we could cast a superclass type directly to a subclass type, what would be the value of these fields (since the superclass type never invoked the subclass constructor)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a mechanism that should work for any Vehicle, without distinguishng between Car and Train - yet you want different behaviour for Car and Train.

So there are several solutions:

1) Split up the mechanism so you have different, typed, callbacks for Car and Train

2) Use polymorphism - provide method(s) in Vehicle that you over-ride differently in Car and Train, and call these in the callbacks.

3) If all else fails, use `instanceof` to detect the actual type of the object before casting it to Car or Train.

Comment: Well I think the problem here is I'm not using the proper mecanism to achieve what I want to do. I'll try other things and let you know if I find something that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As is, you are asking for `new Vehicle()` to produce a `Car` - no compiler or cast will be able to make this work.

What you probably wanted instead is this:

```
interface CompletionCallback<C> {
  Class<C> getType();

  void onCompletion(C object);
}
```

where you would need to check types before calling the callback:

```
for (CompletionCallback<?> c : callBacks) {
  if (c.getType().isAssignableFrom(vehicle)) {
    // Perform some ugly casting here
  }
}
```

OR you could type-check in your callback using `instanceof`.

Javas `EventListenerList` does something similar, too. Again, the inner code involves ugly casting. But the API is nice, because you would register the callback with a type:

```
addCallback(Car.class, new Callback<Car>() {...});
addCallback(Submarine.class, new Callback<Submarine>() { ... });
```

if I recall correctly, it stores the class and callback in an  `Object[]` array internally, and does use casting. But this pattern is nice: register with the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can test using `instanceof` or `YourClass.class.isInstance(OtherClass);` Perhaps you could create an interface for getting your required values and test for that.