# Working with subclasses that have different method names without violating SOLID principles

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, mixins

//interfaces

```
public interface Singer{
    void sing();
}
public interface SongWriter{
    void writeSong();
}
```

//Implementations

```
public class PureSinger implements Singer{
    void sing(){}
}
public class SingerSongWriter implements Singer, SongWriter{
    void sing(){}
    void writeSong(){}
}
```

//Client code

```
void methodA(){
    Singer objPureSinger = new PureSinger();
    Singer objSingerSWer = new SingerSongWriter();

    doSomething(objPureSinger);
    doSomething(objSingerSWer);
}

public void doSomething(Singer obj){
    obj.sing();
    obj.writeSong();    //<--- this does not work.
}
```

In order to acheve this type of code, how should I design the class structure?

Comment: The goal is to control both PureSinger and SingerSongWriter objects with a single base interface/abstract-class object.

Comment: According to your design, you should use `SingerSongWriter` as param of `doSomething()`

Comment: What do you expect `doSomething(objPureSinger);` to do?

Comment: That way, I cannot pass objPureSinger to doSomething()

Comment: Then why don't you accept `SingerSongWriter` instead? Can there be other classes implementing the two interfaces?

Comment: With doSomething(), I would like to control all the objects which are inherited from the Singer interface regardless of the detailed inheritence structure. 
New interface and concrete classes could be newly added in the future.
Does mixin-design solve this type of issue?

Comment: Then what's stopping you from passing `objPureSinger` to the method? What would your method do when passed a `Singer` that doesn't implement `SongWriter`?

Comment: I think I found my friend here, Thank you very much :)

Comment: @yama-san Just for your info, you are supposed to accept and upvote correct answer and upvote other helpful answer. This expects community from everyone. Read this meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner The visitor pattern is an overkill for a requirement of this sort.

Comment: @yama-san Good question. Do check my answer before finalizing the *Visitor Pattern*. While beautiful, the *Vistor Pattern* seems like an overkill for a task where all you need is to ensure that a single interface is used for all your artists.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner See my answer. Hope it helps..

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner : Let us continue this discussion in the comments section of my answer to avoid creating clutter for the question.

Comment: @yama-san I don't fully understand your question. I mean, I don't understand your actual requirements. Why would you want a singer (that only sings, according to its interface) to also write songs in your `doSomething` method? It doesn't make any sense... It's obvious that it will never compile.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Once again, the OP doesn't want the singer to write songs. Instead, the OP wants the singer to sing and the song-writer to write a song. He also wants a singer-song-writer that can sing and write songs. This functionality needs to be supported using a single interface without `doSomething` really worrying about the concrete type passed to it. I agree that the `Singer` interface name is confusing and it could be renamed to `Artist` and `doSomething` could take an `Artist` reference. Hope that clarifies the question. (I have covered the solution in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to acheve this type of code, how should I design the class structure?

Start by defining an `interface` called `Artist` that has a single method called `perform`. Next, define two subclasses namely `Singer` and `SongWriter` each implementing `perform` and containig the code to sing a song and write  a song respectively.

The following two design-patterns would support your use-case really well :

1. The [**Decorator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern : In your case, `Artist` is the *Component*, `Singer` and `SongWriter` are *Concrete Components* and `ArtistDecorator` is your *Abstract Decorator* class. Use the `ArtistDecorator` to wrap a `Singer` into a `SongWriter`. The `doSomething` method takes an `Artist` parameter and is passed the final decorated `Artist` object that wraps a `Singer` into a `SongWriter`.
2. The [**Composite**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern : In your case `Arist` is the *Component*. `CompositeArtist` is the *Composite* and `Singer` and `SongWriter` are the *Leaf* or the *Concrete Component* classes. The `doSomething` method takes an `Artist` parameter. Pass it an instance of the `CompositeArtist` (which *IS-A* `Artist`) and `doSomething` simply calls `perform` which internally iterates through all the `Artist` instances calling their `perform` method one by one.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Regarding your comment about composite pattern not being a good fit here : In case of the composite pattern,the `CompositeAritst` will have an instance of `Singer` and an instance of `SongWriter` in an array/list. Together, this will form the *Composite* of a singer-song-writer. Can you elaborate on what you meant by there are no composites but just single leaf objects?

Comment: Hmmm... I meant that composite is a pattern used to model nested *has-a / has-many* relationships, e.g. the screen has many windows and each window has many widgets. Here you want to use it to model many possible behaviors, turning each possible action (singing and writing songs) into a component. That is an abuse of this pattern IMO, and an overly convoluted solution. Especially, because a `SingerSongWriter` **IS-A** singer that also writes songs, or a song writer that also sings.

Comment: However, I think the decorator approach is a good fit here, so +1

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner If we take the very specific example of a Singer and SongWriter, then yes, the decorator is a better fit. The above answer aims to cover the possible solutions when faced with a situation where a single interface needs to support multiple behaviors. It aims to answer the question title (assuming that the example was presented to support the question title).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assume to use .writeSong() in doSomething() because you are passing in a parameter as *Singer*, and we know that Singer only has a method called .sing(). Here are some options.

1. You should consider what doSomething() actually does in a business logic sense. Maybe we can get rid of calling .writeSong() since the passed in parameter is not always going to be castable to SongWriter.
2. Consider using a base class (e.g. abstract class or concrete class) to implement *Singer* and *SongWriter* to pass that in as the parameter data type instead.
3. If you are looking for a quick fix to make your code run then see below.

Quick fix: 
You need to see if obj is an instanceOf SongWriter first because the passed in parameter is of type *Singer* which doesn't have a method called .writeSong().

```
public void doSomething(Singer obj){
    obj.sing();
    //obj.writeSong();    //<--- this does not work.
    if (obj instanceOf SongWriter) songWriter.writeSong();
}
```

This is a quick fix. You can see from the posts below that you should resort to using instanceOf last.

- [Java generic to avoid ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814115/java-generic-to-avoid-classcastexception)
- [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)

Comment: new interface or new Singer's concrete class could be added in the future, so "if (obj instanceOf) ... " violates the SOLID's OCP.
I need a design which accomplish OCP.

Comment: So you have 2 options. The first is to create a base class to implement both the methods and pass that as the parameter data type. The other option is to not call .writeSong() in doSomething() method (revisit your business requirement).

Answer (score 0):

To quickly answer the question `doSomething` calls both the `sing()` and `writeSong()` methods. Only your `SingerSongWritter` class has both of these defined and so is the only class that can do both. The `objPureSinger` has no definition of what `writeSong` is and so has no idea what to do when called.

If you want to keep this structure one thing you can do to fix this is implement a method in both classes called `do`. In your `PureSinger` class, `do` just simply calls `sing()` but in your `SingerSongWriter` class it calls both `sing()` and `writeSong()`. Finally in your `doSomething` method just call `obj.do();`

Comment: I think it violates the  SOLID'S LSP. Pure singers do not write any song.

Comment: If you want to keep the dosomething method working for both try the new suggestion, it simply adds a method in both classes named the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your class as per your business need. And, it is obvious to get compile time error at

```
public void doSomething(Singer obj){
    obj.sing();
    obj.writeSong();    //<--- compiler will complain here
}
```

Because, `Singer` doesn't have `writeSong` method. As per your current design :

1. All `Singer` CAN only `sing`.
2. All `SongWriter` CAN  only `writeSong`.

But, none of the above can perform both. So, it is obvious `doSomething` won't work until

```
doSomething (SingerSongWriter obj)
```

Because, only `SingerSongWriter` can perform both.